# Filter combo box with grid

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, filter, grid, records

I am using VB.NET 2010, and SQL 2008 r2. I have created a grid and a combo box. When I type for example "abc" in the combo box,the grid should show only records starts with "abc", also the combo box acts the same.

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance,

Hamdi Moussa

Answer (score 1):

For the combo box, there is the auto complete property. I'd suggest looking into that.